# App Script - deleting rows in one sheet based on another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to delete rows in one sheet based on the value of another.

I have been able to get it working based on the position of the rows being the same in both sheets. This will not work for my data as the same value can be in different positions in both sheets. See the images and description below for further details

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhedB.png)

[image]

The 1st sheet has unique identifies, 1st column. Along with yes and no values, 2nd column

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8jLr.png)

[image]

The 2nd sheet just has the unique identifiers. I would like to match the unique identifiers in sheet 1 with sheet 2 and if there is a yes value associated with it in sheet 1 to delete that row in sheet 2. Sheet 2 should look like

[final results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3fJF.png)

[image]

Hope that makes sense. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this, but I will share this way so you can reuse this for some other cases, if needed....

```
function whenTextEqualTo(txt, rng, col, targetCol){   /// Filtering function
    var colNum = col - 1;
    var result = rng.filter(function(ar){
        return ar[colNum] == txt;
    });
    var output = result.map(function (item) {
        return item[targetCol-1];
    });
    return output;
}

function SODeleteRows(){
    const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FIRST_SHEET_NAME");
    const sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SECOND_SHEET_NAME");
    const lastRow1 = sheet1.getLastRow();
    const dataRange = sheet1.getRange(1,1,lastRow1,LAST_COLUMN_IN_FIRST_SHEET).getValues();
    var yesValues = whenTextEqualTo("Yes", dataRange, COLUMN_WHERE_YES_NO_VALUES_ARE, COLUMN_WITH_UNIQUE_VALUES); /// Returns 1D array with only filtered values
    const lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();
    for (var i = lastRow2; i > 0; i--){
        var currentValue = sheet2.getRange(i, COLUMN_WITH_UNIQUE_VALUES_IN_SECOND_SHEET).getValue();
        if(yesValues.indexOf(currentValue) > -1){
            sheet2.deleteRow(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code wild.

Comment: @NEWAZA What do you mean? This code works? This code doesn`t work?

Comment: The original code was, frankly, ugly.  You also have inconsistencies and outdated syntax. You clearly put in effort to help though.

Comment: @NEWAZA Your code is more sophisticated than mine without any doubt. It appeared two days after user asked for help. My code helped to a user (user checked it as solution) and was made according to my interpretation of the user's thought process behind her question. It was written to be more self-explaining and beginner-friendly. If you hate beginner-level solutions and have hard time with code that dont fit to your criteria, then why you are bothering with so simple questions as this? Maybe you are meant for something higher? And, maybe beginners have a right to be beginners as well...

Comment: You okay buddy?

Comment: "This code wild".

Comment: @NEWAZA Here you can start with learning English verbs... https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wish you all the best!

Comment: No you don`t and it is obvious. You just wanted to promote yourself and it is absolutely legitimate. But, you also checked my answer as not helpful, forgetting that if something is not helpful for you, maybe it helped to someone less skilled hour or so after her asked. Someone got help very fast. That is legitimate too. And maybe the purpose of this platform is more than your self-promotion...

Comment: Okay, well I'm leaving this thread now, good luck! Wishing you the best 

Comment: You can continue to be insincere by your will... That have nothing with me...

Answer (score -1):

```
const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const Sheet1 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`)
const Sheet2 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet2`)
```

If you **do not need** to delete rows, but want the data removed:

```
function RemoveTargetIdentifiers() {

  const targetIdentifiers = Sheet1.getDataRange()
                                  .getValues()
                                  .filter(row => row[1] === `Yes`)
                                  .flatMap(row => row[0])

  const updatedValues = Sheet2.getDataRange()
                              .getValues()
                              .filter(row => targetIdentifiers.includes(row[0]))

  Sheet2.getDataRange()
        .clear()

  if (updatedValues.length) return Sheet2.getRange(1, 1, updatedValues.length, updatedValues[0].length)
                                         .setValues(updatedValues)

}
```

If you **need** to delete rows:

```
function DeleteTargetIdentifiers() {

  const targetIdentifiers = Sheet1.getDataRange()
                                  .getValues()
                                  .filter(row => row[1] === `Yes`)
                                  .flatMap(row => row[0])

  const sheet2Values = Sheet2.getDataRange().getValues()

  for (let i = sheet2Values.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

    if (targetIdentifiers.includes(sheet2Values[i][0])) Sheet2.deleteRow(i+1)

  }

}
```